# dynamically instantiate an ng-template and create HTML in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to build a **[typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)** component for use in Angular 5.
I have a **[working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GIiBcO?p=preview)**, as far as I can get it working.

When the component, `type-head` is declared, an `ng-template` is supplied to the component.

```
<type-head>
    <ng-template #hint let-hint="hint">name: {{hint.name}}</ng-template>
</type-head>
```

Each hint should display `name: sam|frodo|pippin` etc.

The `type-head` component is declared as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'type-head',
  template: `
    <input #input class="form-control" />
    <ng-content #content></ng-content>
  `
})
```

When the `typeahead.js` component needs to display a hint, it executes a callback, the `suggest` method which should return HTML content.

At the moment my implementation is as follows:

```
/**
 * TODO: REPLACE THIS FUNCTION WITH A DYNAMIC TEMPLATE
 */
suggest(value:any) {
   return $("<div>name: " + value.name + "</div>");
}
```

I want to replace this implementation with an implementation that uses the `ng-template`. I can render the template using `*ngTemplateOutlet`, but I don't know how to do it dynamically so I can return the HTML.

**My question is:**

> How do I load up the `#hint` `ng-template`, bind the `value` to it, and return the rendered HTML to `typeahead.js` in my **`suggest`** function.

Comment: I will be happy with a this is not possible answer if it can’t be done. Is more information needed?

Comment: Here is an idea https://plnkr.co/edit/6ORQnc?p=preview But you need to care about disposing template

Comment: that's fantastic, I worry about your warning though... disposing... but thanks for the tip, that get's me a lot closer... Maybe I can get the outerHtml of the rendered component (`embeddedView`), and return that after immediately disposing.

Comment: @yurzui I note that each time the embedded views are created, the `vcRef` contains more and more elements in the `_embeddedViews` array; which makes total sense. Do you know how to clear out all the embedded views attached to the `vcRef`, or perhaps recreate the `vcRef` so that it is garbage collected?

Comment: I could then just dump all the prior created views each time new ones are created.

Comment: Try vcRef.clear()

Comment: yea, I already tried that, unfortunately: ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

Comment: Without ViewContainerRef it could look like https://plnkr.co/edit/X1UQEH?p=preview

Comment: that looks awesome, are you reasonably sure when the suggest is removed, that the memory won't leak? To be honest - it's probably so little it doesn't even matter. 
It's a really great solution. Please post an answer so I can accept it. I REALLY appreciate your help with this.

Comment: @yurzui Please post an answer so I can accept it. I REALLY appreciate your help with this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `TemplateRef::createEmbeddedView` method to create embedded view and then obtain DOM node to pass to typeahead as a template:

**parent.html**

```
<type-head>
    <ng-template #hint let-hint="hint">
       <div>name: {{hint.name}}</div>
    </ng-template>
</type-head>
```

**component.ts**

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

suggest(value:any) {
  const embeddedView = this.templateRef.createEmbeddedView({ hint: value });
  embeddedView.detectChanges();
  this.embeddedViews.push(embeddedView);
  return embeddedView.rootNodes[1];
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/X1UQEH?p=preview)**

Comment: But it still requires that you have this `ng-template` hanging somewhere in html. What if I want to have a directive whose sole responsibility would be to create and provide  ng template to its `@Host()`?